# Prevent loading Thumb-2 code on old ARM device

Tags: android, arm

I have an Android app that uses some native code, which the NDK compiles to use the Thumb-2 instruction set. On some really old devices, it will crash with SIGILL when it tries to load because the device's CPU does not support Thumb-2.  I've tried to hack around this by checking if the architecture is "armeabi", but that got tripped up by an armv6l device. What's a good way to avoid loading Thumb-2 code on a device that does not support it?

Comment: Any ARM based Android device is at least ARMv5TE which supports Thumb-2. The reason you're getting SIGILL is probably something else.

Comment: @auslen - Thumb2 was not introduced until ARMv7A. If the library is marked as ARMv7A, then older devices shouldn't try to load it.

Comment: @BitBank You are right, still not fully I think. Looks like Thumb-2 was introduced v6. But then Android world is either v5 or v7. so you are right.

Comment: @BitBank How do you mark a library ARMv7A? Whatever annotations the NDK places into the .so do not prevent System.loadLibrary from loading it on an older device.

Comment: @James - you may be right. Not sure, but I thought the APK doesn't install if the ABI's don't match.

Comment: @BitBank That's only sometimes the case, and, unfortunately, it doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Another thought - the use of Thumb-2 code on Android is optional. You can tell GCC to compile as ARM32 by adding ".arm" to the source file names in your makefile.

Comment: Application.mk: APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a doesn't help?